# Windows Workflow Designer Metadata Editor (vs.net 2010)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, workflow, tfsbuild

Just familiarizing myself with TFS 2010, especially Team Build which now uses Windows Workflow. Have been setting up some custom workflows etc to get used to it and so far so good.

My question is about this blogpost:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2009/12/23/tfs-2010-custom-process-parameters-part-2-metadata.aspx

The author states "By the way, if you use the Workflow Designer in Visual Studio to edit your build process templates, you will see that we have a simple editor for adding Metadata"

Anyone know where to find the metadata designer? I've tried all the obvious spots (right clicking on the loaded template, menus etc), but can't find it!

Answer (score 4):

I have created a series of blog posts to get familiar with the modification of Team Build. See http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/?tag=/build+2010+customization.
 
To answer your question on the metadata, there is in the Arguments a Metadata argument in which you can specify this. See step 20 in http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/17/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-6-Use-custom-type-for-an-argument.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I couldn't find the Metadata either. After reading Ewald Hofman step 20 for several times I found the solution.

Find in the Workflow argument list (The list where you created your own argument) the argument Metadata. Then click in the property window for the Metadata argument the property "Value" and hit the ellipsis button next to it to open the editor.